# Data first in SP, then in External database?

Tags: content-type, design, external-data-column

I have a customer with a customer database which represent projects. The DB only manage approved projects.

I'm working on an application than have to works with project in both early stages (project proposition) and approved projects. The data structure is nearly identical, only few fields will changes, and the status.

I cannot change the project database, but my SharePoint app have to transparently link project proposition and approved project in a unique way, with a higher container (a plan, which is composed with projects).

In a ideal way, the user should manager in the same GUI both kind of projects. Project proposition, in a standard read-write-collaborate sharepoint way, and approved project (read-only, as it should be managed in the legacy projects management).

A project proposition can also be approved eventually. In this case, the project proposition item has to be pushed to the project database, keeping the link for the user perspective (it will probably be a new object).

How should I implement such requirement ?

FYI The target platform is SP 2010 Enterprise, self hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo can create external columns and external lists with BCS to wrap your database and employ them in conjunction with standard SharePoint lists for new types of objects. You can manage what data will be readonly or CRUD-enabled.

Comment: This might help:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/05/05/walkthrough-of-enabling-crud-for-sharepoint-2010-external-lists-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: yes, but the question goes beyond the database link. I'm especially wonderning how to deal with same type of data, sometimes "local", sometimes "external", keeping a single management perspective for users...

Comment: Can you provide more details on requirements? Can you simply create two identical content types one of which is external and add them to the same list?